# Slow startup and shutdown after upgrading ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, 16.04, lts, stable-release-updates

yesterday from terminal I've upgraded ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 from terminal. All is gone well but now there is a really slow start up and also on shutdown, like over than a minute! Can something went wrong? Or I maybe missed something? Thanks in advice to everyone.

Comment: Have you checked to see what is taking so long using bootchart? http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/measure-your-ubuntu-systems-boot-performance-with-boot-chart/

Comment: Could you please post the contents of `/var/log/boot.log` ? Also, could you run `dmesg > ~/dmesg.log` and then post the contents of the dmesg.log file that was created in your home directory?

Comment: @NoBugs I just tried this solution but the problem still persist

Comment: For dmesg > ~/dmesg.log ==> http://pastebin.com/j3gJmGtn

Comment: For /var/log/boot.log I can't open and I used sudo kate /var/log/boot.log and ==> http://pastebin.com/FYJP2Q8e @NickWeinberg

Comment: #SOLVED I solved it with a  clean re-installation. Maybe the problem were into the installation into terminal from 14.04 to 16.04, surely something went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to file in your pastebin link problem was with /etc/fstab file not being configured correctly. It is looking for partition with UUID ef630b6f\x2dae8c\x2d463c\x2d836a\x2dcd18e4f2fe21

Easy way to solve is open your /etc/fstab and check which partition is under problem. After that run command "sudo blkid".
Update the partition UUID with the correct partition that you have.

Your problem should be solved after this.